# Dali 2 - BUS PSU - pull down rate

Tags: dali

I have wired up my DALI network with 2 drivers, a BUS and using the Mikro DALI 2 click boards with an ESP32 for the MCU.

I am able to send BROADCAST commands to switch the lights on/off but when it comes to commissioning them I'm not getting any results, i.e. the drivers are not being addressed.

History: I have this code setup from a previous try with the bus and click board but using DALI 1 drivers. I can't imagine that the bus will be an issue, but it's pointing that way. I have a velleman handheld oscilliscope and measured the minimum V as 3.4v and max at 16.2v.

This is the bus I have ... [Recom Relv4-16](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/led-driver-accessories/9039943/)

This is how the code looks atm ...

```
void initialise() {
    long low_longadd = 0x00;
    long high_longadd = 0xFF;
    long longadd = (long)(low_longadd + high_longadd) / 2;
    uint8_t highbyte;
    uint8_t middlebyte;
    uint8_t lowbyte;
    uint8_t short_add = 0;

    _waitTilLineFree();
    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_BROADCAST_CMD, _DALI2_RESET, 0, 0);
    _waitTilLineFree();
    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_BROADCAST_CMD, _DALI2_RESET, 0, 0);
    _waitTilLineFree();
    
    toggleBroadCast(false);
    _waitTilLineFree();

    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_INITIALISE, 0, 0, 0); //initialise
    _waitTilLineFree();
    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_INITIALISE, 0, 0, 0); //initialise
    _waitTilLineFree();
    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_RANDOMISE_H, 0, 0, 0); //randomise
    _waitTilLineFree();
    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_RANDOMISE_H, 0, 0, 0); //randomise
    _waitTilLineFree();

    printf("Searching fo long addresses:\n");
    printf("INIT LA: %ld", longadd);
    

    while (( longadd <= 0xFF - 2 ) && (short_add <= 64)) {
        while ((high_longadd - low_longadd) > 1) {

            _splitAdd(longadd, &highbyte, &middlebyte, &lowbyte); //divide 24bit adress into three 8bit adresses
            _waitTilLineFree();
            printf("LA: %ld   ", longadd);
            printf("HB: %d    ", highbyte);
            printf("MB: %d    ", middlebyte);
            printf("LB: %d\n", lowbyte);
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_SEARCHADDRH, highbyte, 0, 0); //search HB
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_SEARCHADDRM, middlebyte, 0, 0); //search MB
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_SEARCHADDRL, lowbyte, 0, 0); //search LB
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_COMPARE_H, 0, 0, 0); //compare
            _waitTilLineFree();
            
            if (dali2_getBallastResponse() > 0)
            {
                low_longadd = longadd;
            }
            else
            {
                high_longadd = longadd;
            }

            printf("LLA: %ld\n", low_longadd);
            printf("HLA: %ld\n", high_longadd);
            longadd = (low_longadd + high_longadd) / 2; //center

            printf("DEC: %ld", longadd + 1);
            printf("    ");
            printf("HEX: %#0lX", longadd + 1);
            printf("\n----\n");
        } // second while


        if (high_longadd != 0xFF)
        {
            _splitAdd(longadd + 1, &highbyte, &middlebyte, &lowbyte);
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_SEARCHADDRH, highbyte, 0, 0); //search HB
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_SEARCHADDRM, middlebyte, 0, 0); //search MB
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_SEARCHADDRL, lowbyte, 0, 0); //search LB
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_PROGRAM_SHORT_ADDRESS, 1 + (short_add << 1), 0, 0); //program short adress
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_WITHDRAW_H, 0, 0, 0); //withdraw
            _waitTilLineFree();
            dali2_sendCmd(1 + (short_add << 1), _DALI2_BALLAST_MAX_LEVEL, 0, _DALI2_FOLLOWING_COMMAND);
            vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            sendCommand(short_add, _DALI2_OFF, false);
            _waitTilLineFree();

            printf("Assigning a short address for: %d\n", short_add);
            short_add++;
            

            high_longadd = 0xFF;
            printf("LLA2: %ld\n", low_longadd);
            printf("HLA2: %ld\n", high_longadd);
            longadd = (long)(low_longadd + high_longadd) / 2;

        }
        else {
            printf("End\n");
        }
            printf("LONG ADD NOW: %ld\n", longadd);
            printf("\n~~~~~~~~\n");
    } // first while

    printf("TERMINATE INIT\n");
    dali2_sendCmd(_DALI2_TERMINATE_H_BITS, 0, 0, 0);  //terminate
    toggleBroadCast(true);  //broadcast on
}
```

I am following this logic from this [tutorial: NabiyevTR](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/NabiyevTR/simple-dali-controller-506e44)

This has worked for me in the past with arduino, maybe I've missed something on the copy and paste, translation of it all.

NOTE: the _waitTilLineFree() function has a blocking while loop to check if the status is NOT in_action then a delay of 20ms

```
void _waitTilLineFree()
{
    while (_daliState!=_DALI2_NO_ACTION)
    {
        //wait for response
    }
    vTaskDelay(20 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
```

Not sure if this is enough information to go off, but comment and I'll try my best to get more info to debug from.

Comment: Are there any signal integrity issues.

Comment: signal integrity issues? How do you mean? Well if a broadcast signal works isn't that a sign that the comms links are working at least from the master to the driver

Comment: I was thinking there might be collisions with random replies.

Comment: okay I will try this wired up with 1 driver and see what happens, to rule out the collisions theory.

Comment: Good then at the same time validate the bit stream for valid protocol

Comment: on a side note I again refered back to the arduino tutorial and the guy uses 0xFFFFFF for high_longadd which is != 0xFF. I changed that and now I'm getting some responses b